# Encoding binary file chunk by chunk fails

Tags: python, encode, binaryfiles

The Zip file I need to encode seems to be too heavy and the method below gives me error:

```
with open("/tmp/pdf/pdffiles.zip", "rb") as f:
    binary_file = f.read()
    encoded = base64.b64encode(binary_file)

self.download_zip = encoded
```

so I tried to chunk it but the file I finaly download is damaged,
can anyone take a look at the following code and give me any hint please:

```
zipfile = open("/tmp/pdf/pdffiles.zip", "rb")
encoded = False
while True:
    chunk = zipfile.read(8192) 
    if not chunk:
        break
    if encoded:
        encoded += base64.b64encode(chunk)
    else:   
        encoded = base64.b64encode(chunk)
zipfile.close()


self.download_zip = encoded
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When chunking base64, it's important that your chunk sizes are multiples of 6, otherwise the data won't concatenate properly. You can try a number like `8208` and it should work.